Force Framework to load correct Assembly Version
I have a plugin in another program with a dependency that throws a TypeLoadException at runtime because it can't find a type in an old version of one of it's dependencies:
Host Program (.Net Framework 4.8, WPF)
-> loads System.Text.Json 4.0.1.2
Plugin (.Net Framework 4.8, WPF)
-> references IdentityModel.OidcClient 6.0.0 (.Net Standard 2.0)
  -> references System.Text.Json 8.0.5

So at runtime IdentityModel.OidcClient tries to load a type from System.Text.Json 8.0.5, but can't find it, because the framework only loads System.Text.Json 4.0.1.2, which the causes an exception.
This happens even if my plugin itself references System.Text.Json 8.0.5 (with binding redirects), and I force load the correct version of the assembly (Assembly.Load(...)). So although both versions of the assembly are loaded (checked in the debugger), and IdentityModel.OidcClient should have a clear dependency on the later version, it still only gets served the older 4.0.1.2 version.
When I attach to the AppDomain and listen to the Type and Assembly Resolve events, the specific type and/or assemble (System.Text.Json) is never asked for.
Because of the host program, and the dependency of a dependency there is little I can do directly to force the correct version, as far as I know. Why is this happening? Is there anything I can do to force the version, besides going to the IdentityModel.OidcClient and pushing a PR to set AutoGenerateBindingRedirects to true?
Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerContext' from assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.'


Not an answer per say, but we have faces similar issues with net48/netstandard2.0/net6.0 dependency hell -- everything compiles, but runtime we have gotten weird error messages, indicating that they are not really supported for the target framework.
Our strategy is moving away from netstandard2.0, and rather letting net48 projects explicitly targeting packages that actually supports net framework
